# Multithreaded app has problems re-opening files - Windows taking too long to close?

Tags: c++, multithreading, fopen, fclose

I have a multithreaded app that opens a few files (read-only) and does a bunch of calculations based on data in those files.  Each thread then generates some output files.

The code runs fine so long as I generate the threads and then delete them then the app exits.  If, however, I try to put the thread creation/deletion into a subroutine and call it several times then the threads have problems when they try to re-open the input files.  I have an if(inFile==NULL) check within each thread and sometimes that gets triggered but sometimes it just crashes.  Regardless, each thread has an fclose() for each file and the threads are properly terminated so the files should always be closed before the threads are recreated.

I can create multiple threads that can open the same input files and that works fine.  But if I close those threads and re-create new ones (e.g. by repeatedly calling a subroutine to create the threads) then I get errors when the threads try to re-open the input files.

The crashes are not predictable.  Sometimes I can loop through the thread creation/deletion process several times, sometimes it crashes on the second time, sometimes the fourth, etc.

The only thing I can think of is that the OS (Windows 7) takes too long to close the file sometimes, so the next thread is spawned before the file is closed and then there's some kind of error due to the fact that the OS is trying to close the file while the thread is trying to open it.  It seems to me that that could trigger the if(inFile==NULL) condition.

But, sometimes when the if(inFile==NULL) condition is *not* triggered I still get jibberish read in from the input file.  So it thinks it has a good file pointer but it clearly does not.

I realize this is probably a tough question to answer but I'm stumped.  So maybe someone has an idea.

Thanks in advance,

rgames

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Is there a chance that 2 threads want to open a file at the same time?

Comment: Impossible even to make a good guess as to what you are doing wrong without seeing what you are doing. Like n.m. said, MCVE. (Wild guess -- threads are accidentally using the same FILE*. But it could be any kind of error that produces undefined behavior.)